# Rails Cache Doesn't Return As Objects, but Strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I'm using redis as cache store, and I want to cache common data

```
@links = Rails.cache.fetch "FriendsLinks" do
    Link.where(category_id: 0)
end
```

But data returned from `Rails.cache.fetch` is a `String`, not an array of `List` objects.

I have to delete the cache from redis, then the next request would work. But very often, it will break again.

Edit:
it happens only at Development environment

Comment: What kind of string you get?

Comment: @charinten it's the serialized result of list objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've located the problem.

the problem is the related Model hasn't been load when data retrieved from redis/memcache. So ruby cannot perform unmarshal.

Simple solution is to set

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

the drawback is you have to restart your app when you make code changes.

Another one is just put the related Class before Rails.cache, such as

```
Link
@links = Rails.cache.fetch "FriendsLinks" do
    Link.where(category_id: 0)
end
```

Or create a initializer and put it under config/initializers

```
if Rails.env == "development"
    Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb") do |model_name|
        require_dependency model_name
    end
end
```